# Solr indexes don't incrementally update after rebuilding

Tags: solr

We are on version 8 update 2. We have one CM and 2 CDs. All indexes are set to manual strategy on CDs. CM does all the indexing. All master db indexes are set to sync master and all web indexes to onpublishendasync.

We are having a strange issue in one of our environments. 2 of the web indexes are not being updated incrementally. The issue has happened a few times. All the other web indexes with the same strategy work fine - onpublishendasync. The web indexes that work show a message in the logs that they were updated but the problem ones don't.

We checked the indexes to see if their crawling was paused or stopped but Sitecore shows all of them as Started.

Has anyone ever come across this issue?

Comment: Can you provide us with Sitecore version information, a high level of your environment (number and types of instances) and the role(s) of the instance(s) you've been reproducing the issue on?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: And which indexes is this happening for? Are they custom?  If not, can you name them?

Comment: Its happening for a custom web indeed and sitecore_web_index.

Comment: Do the all the indexes share the same configuration? Could there be a computed field that is erroring?

Comment: Let me set the logs to DEBUG and see if I find anything. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: We set the CRAWLING log to DEBUG this is the error message we received, [Index=sitecore_web_index] Event Queue is empty. Incremental update returns. Any ideas? This is only happening for sitecore_web_index and that one custom index and no other indexes. There are no computed field errors in the logs either.

Comment: are the items that are being updated under the root path for the problem indexes crawlers?

Comment: Yes, the root path is configured correctly for the indexes.